# Счетчик лайков ката решение

Tags: javascript

Есть задача (ката с кодварс) :
Реализуйте функцию likes :: [String] -> String, которая должна принимать входной массив, содержащий имена людей, которым нравится элемент. Он должен вернуть отображаемый текст, как показано в примерах.

> 

```
likes [] // must be "no one likes this"
likes ["Peter"] // must be "Peter likes this"
likes ["Jacob", "Alex"] // must be "Jacob and Alex like this"
likes ["Max", "John", "Mark"] // must be "Max, John and Mark like this"
likes ["Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"] // must be "Alex, Jacob and 2 others like this"
```

> 

Для 4 или более имен число and 2 others просто увеличивается.

> Мое решение

```js
function likes(names) {
var like = '';
if (names.length === 0) {
  like = 'no one likes this';
}
else if (names.length === 1) {
  like = (names[0] + ' likes this');
 }
 else if (names.length === 2) {
   like = (names[0] + ' and ' + names[1] + ' like this');
 }
  else if (names.length === 3) {
    like = (names[0] + ', ' + names[1]+ ' and ' + names[2] + ' like this');
}
  else if (names.length >= 4) {
    like = (names[0] + ', ' + names[1] + ' and ' + (names.length -2) + ' others' + ' like this');
  }
  return like;
}
```

Понимая что решение очень массивное,хотел бы увидеть более изящное решение.Заранее всем спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю на сколько прикольно данное решение,

Можно соорудить например такое:

```js
function likes(names) {
  if (!names.length) return 'no one likes this';
  const arrStr = [
    names[1] ? (names.length == 2 ? ' and ' + names[1] : ',' + names[1]) : '',
    names.length < 4 ? (names[2] ? ' and ' + names[2] : '') : (' and ' + (names.length - 2) + ' others'),
    names.length == 1 ? ' likes' : ' like'
  ]
  const result = `${names[0]}#s this`;
  return result.replace('#s', arrStr.join(''));
}

const names = ["Peter"];
const names1 = ["Jacob", "Alex"];
const names2 = ["Max", "John", "Mark"];
const names3 = ["Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"];

console.log(likes(names));
console.log(likes(names1));
console.log(likes(names2));
console.log(likes(names3));
```

Или так например в строку:

```js
function likes(names) {
  if (!names.length) return 'no one likes this';
  return `${names[0]}${names[1] ? (names.length == 2 ? ' and ' + names[1] : ',' + names[1]) : ''}${names.length < 4 ? (names[2] ? ' and ' + names[2] : '') : (' and ' + (names.length - 2) + ' others')} ${names.length == 1 ? 'likes' : 'like'} this`
}

const names = ["Peter"];
const names1 = ["Jacob", "Alex"];
const names2 = ["Max", "John", "Mark"];
const names3 = ["Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"];

console.log(likes(names));
console.log(likes(names1));
console.log(likes(names2));
console.log(likes(names3));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Ооо, помню такую "Кату". Я решал 2 способами:

```
function likes(names) {
  if(names.length === 0) return "no one likes this";
  if(names.length === 1) return names[0] + " likes this";
  if(names.length === 2) return names[0] + " and " + names[1] + " like this";
  if(names.length === 3) return names[0] + ", " + names[1] + " and " + names[2] + " like this";
  return names[0] + ", " + names[1] + " and " + (names.length - 2) + " others like this";
}
```

и Вот так:

```
function likes(names) {
  switch(names.length){
    case 0:
      return `no one likes this`;
    case 1: 
      return `${names[0]} likes this`;
    case 2: 
      return `${names[0]} and ${names[1]} like this`;
    case 3: 
      return `${names[0]}, ${names[1]} and ${names[2]} like this`;
    default: 
      return `${names[0]}, ${names[1]} and ${names.length - 2} others like this`;
  }
}
```

Суть одна и та же, просто разные конструкции)

Comment: Спасибо большое!